# Resizing a container while transforming the contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking to put a Mapbox map into a container that is X,Y in size. Then I need to have a slider that, when adjusted, will simultaneously resize the div and scale the map at an inverse proportion. This might sound like simple zooming in on a map, but the desired effect is that the div appears to remain the same size but a wider portion of the map comes into view while maintaining the same zoom level on the map, effectively I'm widening the view port of the map, but keeping the container's viewport on the page the same size.

My initial thoughts on the implementation would be something like this:

```
    #map{ width: 250px; height: 250px; }
```

then the slider input value of .5, we would perform a
transform: scale(0.5);
and simultaneously increase the div to 500px,500px

I've created testbed here if anyone has some thoughts: http://jsfiddle.net/cdubbs/91uj9ce7/

Is something like this even possible? Or is there an alternative way to do this (whether it would perform faster or be more widely compatible)?

Comment: Are we trying to zoom out or in? I'm not following that part. I've got the map scaling separate from the container div.

Comment: @hopkins-matt I'm trying to keep the zoom at the same level, certain map layers disappear at lower (zoomed out) levels and so I'm trying to make things so that you are still able to see those details if you're trying to look at a larger map area while maintaining the same dimensions on the page. Does that make sense?

Comment: So we are trying to zoom out/show a wider area without changing the zoom level. Gotcha. Let me see what I can come up with.

Comment: @hopkins-matt yep, I'm just avoiding the term zoom out, so as not to be confused with actually zooming the map, but I think you get it. Widening the view of the map within the same container dimensions while maintaining a constant zoom level.

Comment: Is there any issue with placing the current map `<div>` within another container?

Comment: @hopkins-matt nope, whatever you need to make it happen!

Comment: I think this is my last question. ha ha. Will the map always be square?

Comment: Scratch that last one. It'll work if it's square or rectangular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not gonna lie... this solution is kind of "hack"-y, but it works.

**Update:** Now works with Firefox & IE(Only tested on IE11)

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/hopkins_matt/91uj9ce7/13/

HTML:

```
<div id="map" style="width: 250px; height: 250px;"></div>

<input type="range" min="10" max="100" value="100" class="scale" step="1" oninput="scaleMap(value)" onchange="scaleMap(value)" id="scale">
<output for="fader" id="percentage">100</output>
```

JS:

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = '* insert access token *';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map', // container id
  style: 'https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-styles/styles/outdoors-v7.json', //stylesheet location
  center: [40, -74.50], // starting position
  zoom: 9 // starting zoom
});

function scaleMap(percentage) {
    document.querySelector('#percentage').value = percentage;
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById("map");
    var initialWidth = mapDiv.offsetWidth;
    var initialHeight = mapDiv.offsetHeight;
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas");
    function divSize(multiplier) {
        return (100 / percentage) * multiplier;
    }
    var mapScale = (percentage / 100);
    mapDiv.style.width = divSize(initialWidth) + "px";
    mapDiv.style.height = divSize(initialHeight) + "px";
    mapCanvas[0].style.width = divSize(initialWidth) + "px";
    mapCanvas[0].style.height = divSize(initialHeight) + "px";
    mapCanvas[0].width = divSize(initialWidth);
    mapCanvas[0].height = divSize(initialHeight);
    map.resize();
    mapCanvas[0].style.transform = "scale(" +mapScale+")";
    mapCanvas[0].style.marginLeft = (((divSize(initialWidth) - initialWidth) / 2) * -1) + "px";
    mapCanvas[0].style.marginTop = (((divSize(initialHeight) - initialHeight) / 2) * -1) + "px";
    document.getElementById("map").style.width = initialWidth + "px";
```

CSS:

```
#map {
    overflow: hidden;
    position:relative;
}

#map div canvas {
    padding: 0;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```